# How to find all text fields in a window?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have a window with two text fields inside it.

How can I get the handles of **both** text fields using WinAPI calls?

Note: Both text boxes belong to a different application (I make the WinAPI calls in application A and the text boxes are located in application B).

**Update 1:**

I get `Invalid window handle` message when invoking `GetClassName`.

I suppose that something is wrong with my declaration of the callback function.

`EnumChildWindows` is invoked from one of the methods of `TMyClass` like this:

```
EnumChildWindows(handle, @TMyClass.CBList, 0);
```

Here's the code of the callback function.

```
function TMyClass.CBList(Win: THandle; lp: LPARAM): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  ClassName:array [1..1024] of Char;
begin
  GetClassName(Win, PChar(@ClassName), 1024);
  OutputDebugString(PChar('SysErrorMessage(GetLastError): '));

  result := true;
end;
```

Comment: Can you use the handles returned by the constructors?

Comment: I have following situation: I have application A in Delphi and this application interacts via WinAPI with application B. I have the source code of application A, but not the source code of application B.

Therefore - no, I can't get these values from constructors because they are in application B.

Comment: The application B is written in Delphi as well.

Comment: is it correct to pass function *of object* to plain C win32 API `EnumChildWindows` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use FindWindow or EnumWindows to find the top level window of the target application.
2. Call EnumChildWindows to enumerate all children of the top level window.
3. In the enumeration callback use GetClassName to check for the desired window class. It would be EDIT for a raw Win32 edit window, for example.

Use a tool like Spy++ to understand the structure of the target app, and find out the precise window class names that it uses.

---

Your questions in the comments about how to call `GetClassName` got me thinking. If you are using XE3, you could write a simple type record helper for `HWND` to make it syntactically cleaner to get hold of the class name:

```
type
  THWNDHelper = record helper for HWND
  private
    function GetClassName: string;
  public
    property ClassName: string read GetClassName;
  end;

function THWNDHelper.GetClassName: string;
var
  Buffer: array [0..255] of Char;
begin
  if Winapi.Windows.GetClassName(Self, @Buffer, Length(Buffer))=0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result := Buffer;
end;
```

And then you can write `hwnd.ClassName` to obtain the window class name. Of course, if you are not using XE3 you can do it like this:

```
function GetWindowClassName(hwnd: HWND): string;
var
  Buffer: array [0..255] of Char;
begin
  if GetClassName(hwnd, @Buffer, Length(Buffer))=0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result := Buffer;
end;
```

Note that I am using a buffer length of 256 since window class name lengths are limited to be no longer than that.

---

Regarding the code in the update, you must not use an instance method for the callback. The callback must be declared like this:

```
function EnumChildWindowsCallback(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(GetWindowClassName(hwnd)));
  Result := True;
end;
```

This is made clear in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633493.aspx). Unfortunately the declaration of `EnumChildWindows` in `Windows.pas` completely abandons type safety of the callback function. So you have to get it right without help from the compiler.

Note also that `HWND` and `THandle` are not the same thing. Don't mix them up.

Comment: Ad step 3: Is this the correct way to read the class name of the current control to ClassName variable? `GetClassName(Win, PAnsiChar(ClassName), 1024)` where `ClassName:array [1..1024] of Char;`.

Comment: Use `PChar(@ClassName)`, or `@ClassName[1]` for the second parameter.

Comment: How can I print `ClassName` in the debug ouput? `OutputDebugString(PChar('ClassName: ' + ClassName));` doesn't work (produces output like `ClassName: `).

Comment: Also, the class name is not allowed to be greater than 256 characters in length, so that's the size you should use for your array.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko OK, I think I've got that sorted now. Ideally that should have been a new question, but I decided to help you here 'cos I'm feeling gentle today!!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your statement about `EnumChildWindowsCallback`: I somehow need to pass the handle of the found text fields back into the method, which invokes the method. The purpose of the entire activity is to get handles of ALL text fields in a dialog box (so that later in the method I can interact with them). To do this, I intended to write the handles of found text fields into member variables of `TMyClass`. If it's impossible, I'm wondering how I can do this (save handles found in the callback function in `TMyClass`).

Comment: Note to the last comment: Is there any alternative to saving the handles in global variables?

Comment: Don't use globals. Use `lParam` to communicate between the calling code and the callback. For example, pass `LPARAM(Self)` when calling `EnumChildWindows`. Then  you can use `TMyClass(lParam)` in the callback.